# I have ant error how to proceed?

Tags: xml, ant, liferay, java, build.xml

I'm a beginner in Liferay portal , when I try to compile my file : build.xml , those errors appear :

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\PFA\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.0-ce-ga1-20120106155615760\build-common-plugin.xml:407: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\PFA\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.0-ce-ga1-20120106155615760\build-common.xml:94: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

The current version of :

- JDK : 1.6
- ANT : 1.8.3

Comment: Have you tried googling the second line?

Comment: Yes I had searched and I tried some solutions , but it does'n work

Comment: Please do your homework, seems like it is jdk version issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Ant giving me a Unsupported major.minor version error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073485/why-is-ant-giving-me-a-unsupported-major-minor-version-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do most likely not only have Java 6 installed, but a mixture of different Java versions. Either configure them to use one and only one (JRE/JDK) or uninstall all versions that you don't need.

You can also find more information in this question: [Why is Ant giving me a Unsupported major.minor version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073485)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a new environement variable ANT_HOME and set its path as  C:....\ant_apache1.8.3 and call it in my PATH  by %ANT_HOME%\bin 
It's working now .

for more details : 

[Ant Apache](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html)