# Error in a build.xml when using ANT

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant

I write a java package, and I want to compile it into .class files first and then package it. Following codes are what I do in my ant script. Under the directory of "src/compressScript" are four java class I wrote.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><project basedir="."default="compileJava" name="compileJava">


<target name="compileJava">
        <mkdir dir="buildTest"/>
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src/compressScript" destdir="buildTest"/>
</target>

</project>
```

When I try to use javac task of ANT to run this scirpt, the error is like this:
Buildfile: C:\Users\di_yu\workspace\AffirmedNetworks\buildTest.xml
compileJava:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\di_yu\workspace\AffirmedNetworks\buildTest.xml:6:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Total time: 545 milliseconds
```

I check my compiler, the installed JRE is JRE 7.0 and the compiler compliance level is 1.7. So what's the problem?

Comment: Version 52 is java 1.8 Do you have any Java1.8 dependencies?

Comment: I installed java 1.8 but I think I do not use it. So how can I eliminated from java 1.8?

Comment: In your command line, have you tried java -version??

Comment: opps... it is java 1.8. But in eclipse, it is java 1.7 set. How can I change this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Ant giving me a Unsupported major.minor version error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073485/why-is-ant-giving-me-a-unsupported-major-minor-version-error)