# How to solve??? UnsupportedClassVersionError is occured to run the build.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, build

Change the Java Compiler of the Eclipse(Luna) from 1.7 to 1.6, then the Java file runs fine but in the time to run the build.xml, the following error is occurred...

BUILD FAILED
build.xml:47: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

build.xml file is...

```
<property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../Softwares/eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/"/>
    <property name="junit.output.dir" value="junit"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.6"/>
    <path id="Referenced Libraries.userclasspath"/> ... ... ... <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>
    <target name="ExampleTest">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="org.idmunit.ExampleTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="IdMUnitTests.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
    <target name="junitreport">
        <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Eclipse/Installation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation):

> Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) was released on June 25, 2014.
>
> A **Java 7 JRE/JDK** is required for most of the Luna package downloads based on Eclipse 4.4.

See [Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/3536342) for more information regarding the specific error.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your question was already answered here: [Why is Ant giving me a Unsupported major.minor version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073485/why-is-ant-giving-me-a-unsupported-major-minor-version-error)

It seems likely that you just need to set your ant JRE from 6 to 7